# Cut/paste file between folders no longer keep the original folder permissions

Tags: permissions, ntfs

In NTFS drives, the behavior used to be that, when a file was moved, it would retain the permissions of the original file, if the move was made to a folder on the same volume.

I know this by experience and it can be seen here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310316

But I was trying to show this behavior today to a colleague and it just didn't work. Every single time the file would simply have the permissions from the new folder associated to it.

I've tried in 3 different machines and it no longer works like that. When did it change? And no, the registry setting mentioned previously isn't set.

Any idea when this changed?

*[Edit]*

Just an example to make it more clear

Suppose I have these folders, in my C drive.

- C:\Shared

  - \Working
  - \Final

And I have four groups: 
 - Interns
 - Employees
 - Managers
 - Staff (that has the previous 3 as members).

Now, let's consider the permissions (simplified).

- C:\Shared

  - Does not inherit
  - Explicitly allows Total Control to Admins
  - Explicitly allows Modify to Managers
- C:\Shared\Working

  - Inherits from Shared
  - Explicitly allows Modify to Employees
- C:\Shared\Final

  - Inherits from Shared
  - Explicitly allows Read to Staff

Now, let's supposed I have a file in the Working folder, called Bullshit.doc.

Previously, if the file was moved (cut/pasted) from the Working to the Final folder, it would retain the original permissions, i.e., Managers and Staff could Modify and Interns would have no permissions.

Now, when I try moving the Bullshit.doc, when moved, will simply inherit the permissions from the Final folder, i.e., it simply forgives that Interns shouldn't have access.

My question is: this changed, didn't it? Or I am going crazy? I'm 99% sure that it worked just like described in the KB.

I know I had problems similar to this in the past, when upper level users moved files between folders (with different set of permissions) and then complained that the interns couldn't read the files. I had to explain more than once that cut/paste wouldn't work, that they need to copy/paste/delete. It was back on Windows 2003 for sure, but I could be at least 2008 R2.

[Edit 2] Now with pictures!!!

Ok, so I decided to try and replicate. With the actual files and not simple examples. Here it is...

So this is the source folder. See all the implicit permissions and the one explicit permission. 
[image: Some folder]

Now, let's create a file in there. And check it permissions. [image: Just a random document]

Time to move the file to the destination. The original folder was just a temp folder. Let's check the destination folder permissions.
[image: Way less convoluted permissions]

After moving the folder, let's check its permissions...
[image: WTAF!!!]

Hum... not what I'd expect it. Even if it was just a file, from what I gathered in the KB above, it should keep the permissions. And that's how I remember it behaving.

But it seems it changed. And I can't find an official source of when it happened.

This makes makes me doubt my sanity.

Comment: Permission Inheritance can override this behavior. If the new folder inherits, the contents do not explicitly sever inheritance, and the source and destination containers do not inherit from the same ACL list, there will be differences in the resulting permissions. Also note that Windows Resource Protection (the mechanism that allows UAC to prompt in conjunction with permissions) requires more variation in permission ACLs throughout the filesystem (for instance, the program files and windows directories do not inherit from C, and user homes all have differant non-inherited permissions).

Comment: I added an example, to clarify. I really don't think that has anything to do with Permission inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) is still evolving and changing. I believe that the changes to the
handling of inherited permissions has first appeared in Vista and has further
evolved in Windows 7.
The registry setting in your link dates from XP, so as far as I know it is
ignored in newer versions.

To understand what happens when one copies/moves a file, one must first
understand the difference between implicit and explicit permissions.

**Implicit permissions** are inherited from the parent folder, so are stored with
the parent folder. They are not stored with the children and therefore are not
movable/copiable. In other words, these permissions only apply while the child
is in its parent folder, because they come from the parent.

**Explicit permissions** are given manually to the folder/file and are stored in
[Access Control Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) (ACL) as NTFS attributes.
They can be considered as belonging to the item and may in some cases
be moved with it if the target file-system is also NTFS.

Some consequences of this NTFS architecture are :

- When a folder/file is **copied**, new target entries are created in the NTFS tables
  of the target folder.
  Therefore the copied file will lose all explicit permissions, and will
  only inherit from its new parent folder.
- When a file/folder is **moved inside the same volume**,
  its NTFS entry is moved, complete with all contained attributes and permissions.
  Therefore it will retain all explicit permissions,
  but will lose its old inherited permissions,
  gaining instead those of its new parent folder.
- When a folder/file is **moved between different volumes**,
  the move is treated as a copy and will retain none of the original permissions.
  The only difference from copy is by the source being deleted when the copy is complete.
- A file/folder that only has inherited permissions,
  has no permissions to move.
  Such an item will always inherit its permissions from the parent folder.
- A folder/file may be marked as non-inheriting permissions from its parent.
  In that case, all its permissions are stored with it as ACLs, meaning
  as explicit permissions.

This goes against most established documentation, where it is usually claimed that
when a folder/file is moved a inside the same volume, it will retain its original NTFS
permissions, both implicit and explicit.
This was maybe once true in older versions of Windows,
but was verified by myself and by the poster
as no longer being the case for implicit permissions in Windows 7 and Windows 10.

For an example of erroneously-documented move rules, see the article
[How file and folder permissions are handled while moving or copying files on Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7](http://winplat.net/2011/04/08/how-file-and-folder-permissions-are-handled-while-moving-or-copying-files-on-windows-2008-r2-and-windows-7/). This article was the source of my discussion below
with the poster, where we discovered together the true rules that govern copy and
move in NTFS.

Comment: Hi Harry. I tried applying the rules to the example I gave, and it behaves differently. The rules stated above are exactly how I think it would behave. But when I try to reproduce it ends up ignoring the explicit permissions. Have you tried applying the rules to the example given?

Comment: You need to define you case exactly. But as above, the fact that a file is in a folder does not mean that the folder permissions will move with it - only permissions granted *explicitly to the file itself*, or granted to the folder but with propagation to the children (propagation only works for existing files and new ones will only inherit).

Comment: I thought the example case was pretty clear. Anyhow, I tried with folders and explicit permissions. When moved, the folder didn't retain the original permissions. I guess I'll edit the question later with pictures and examples.

Comment: Is your case a move on same volume? And which Windows version? Yes - some examples of non-retained permissions would be useful.

Comment: And are you moving files or a folder?

Comment: I tried with both. Same behavior.

Comment: Updated with example. Looking at your source, it should retain all implicit/explicit permissions, not inheriting permissions from destination folder (Same volume, from Folder A to Folder B).

Comment: Which Windows version? Windows 10? And what user account is doing the move?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2, an admin is doing the move.

Comment: I have tested this on Windows Server 2012 R2 with local accounts, and everything works as expected. Are you using a domain or local administrator account?

Comment: Local Admin. When you moved the files, fom the same volume, did it keep the original permissions? I'm about to give on understanding what's happening here.

Comment: Moving within C: kept the original permissions. Last gasp question: Is it possible that one of the folders isn't real, for example a link, so you are not really moving inside the same volume?

Comment: No, both are folders. Not junctions/hard links/whatever.

Comment: Absolutely last gasp question:Can it be caused by some installed product? To test boot in Safe mode.

Comment: I don't think so. Of the programs installed, only McAffee would affect it, I guess. But I don't think it is. Since the tests were done on a prod server, I can't really test it now. I will try to replicate it on a VM. And I'b de really pissed if the problem lies with McAfee.

Comment: My tests were done on a VM with nearly-vanilla Server 2012 Essentials. I don't *know* if the differences in results were caused by some installed product, but I can say that my company sometimes had problems when McAffee was imposed on us by a client (I'm explicitly *not* pointing the finger at McAffee).

Comment: I tested it again, on my machine. Win 10 Pro, no McAfee, no domain. Just Kaspersky. Created a folder called "Shared" with two folders. Created local groups. Gave different permissions to the folders. Created a file inside folder1. Moved to folder2. It just assumed the new folder permissions. Created another file. Move to a folder outside Shared. Same thing. The only thing remotely similar is when I move the folder with explicit permissions. Then it holds the explicit permissions. But it does not brings the old parent folder permissions. That's really now how I remember. I give up.

Comment: I have also seen in my test that inherited permissions changed - I was wrongly under the impression that you were worried about explicit permissions. It seems like there were changes done in Windows 10 to the move mechanism. Apparently now the moved file loses its old inherited permissions and gains new ones. I myself find this much more logical for the file's directory entry to simply be moved between folders together with its existing ACLs, with the effect of inherited permissions being replaced.

Comment: I have tested this on Windows 7, and it works identically to Windows 10. I really don't understand the claims found everywhere that implicit permissions are conserved when moving. I will modify my answer above accordingly when I have the time. Maybe this was done differently in XP - maybe once inherited permissions were stored with the children rather than with the parents, which is of course much less efficient for Windows when parent permissions change. The change probably started with Vista.

Comment: As I said, consider my new answer as containing a new discussion regarding explicit and implicit permissions in view of ACLs stored with the child, so parent permissions inherited implicitly from the parent are not movable.

Comment: That's what odd. I also tested with Windows 7 and the behavior is basically the same. It contradicts the documents I see and my memory. But maybe I'm being betrayed by my memory, because I think the folder had explicit permissions. The reason is the folder/files were created by a scanner. I guess it had rights to create files and the creator had different permissions. But I digress. I'll probably assign you the points since you were the only one that even tried to help after a bounty was set. Unless someone posts here on the last minutes with a swooping excellent answer.

Comment: Your memory, like mine, may date from XP. I also believed the documents, but their authors may also have had too-long memories. I'll rewrite my swooping excellent answer this evening.

Comment: Done. Thanks to Luiz Angelo for an interesting post that has forced me to re-examine empirically and critically my knowledge and existing documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional important detail to add to harrymc's excellent and comprehensive explanation, and this detail ends up causing split behaviour, where a file move sometimes behaves in the 2003-style and sometimes in the 2008-style.

The manner in which NTFS intra-volume moves was updated in 2008/Vista and above is not a complete overhaul, but just adding a second step in the background.

**Step 1)** MFT is updated; the file is moved and retains original permissions
*(Just like in 2003/XP and earlier. Moves on those OSes stop at this step.)*

**Step 2)** ACLs are updated to drop the original parent folder's inherited permissions and apply the new parent folder's inherited permissions.
*(This is the additional step that 2008/Vista added so files will have the target folder's permissions.)*

However, if the user who is performing the move has *Modify* rights and does not explicitly have the *Change Permissions* right, step 2 will fail (but not tell you), and you will end up with the old-school behavior so it seems like things are back in 2003 again.

In this same scenario, if someone copies the file and then deletes the original (the same way the file system handles a move between volumes), everything works the way you would expect it to.

There isn't any graceful solution - you either give users *Change Permissions* rights so **Step 2** can succeed, or any files moved between different-permission folders on the same file server volume will retain their original permissions until they are forcibly re-propagated.

Comment: This is an addition to an existing answer and not an answer in itself. Please post it as a comment.